# Python: How to set a value from JSON as the index in a list?

Tags: python, json, list

I'm trying to read a dataset and set the integer value of the JSON file as the array of the list. This is the example JSON file,

```
[{
"index_id": "1234",
"text": "hello world",
},
{
"index_id": "5678",
"text": "roses are red",
}]
```

Right now, I have just tried with reading the JSON file and putting everything to a defaultdict(list), this messes things up. Assume I read everything to **L1**

If I try to get **L1[1234]** this would give an error as **1234** is not a valid index in the L1 and the indexes are 0,1.

If L1 was printed,

```
{u'1234': u'hello world'}, {u'5678': u'roses are red'}]
```

I understand that the list has my potential value for the index as a value stored and in unicode (makes it worse).

So how to turn **L1** into or a method so if I try to pull up **L1[1234]** it would pull up the **'hello world'**,

```
{1234: u'hello world'}, {5678: u'roses are red'}]
```

Thank you

Edited: Changed the JSON.

Comment: This is not `json`. this is list of two different `dicts/json`

Comment: I edited the question now.

Comment: Instead if you could show sample of dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of dicts you could do something like this:

```
json_lst = [{
    "1234": "hello world"
}, 
{
    "5678": "roses are red"
}]

result = {int(k) : v  for element in json_lst for k, v in element.items()}
print(result[1234])
```

**Output**

```
hello world
```

The above dictionary comprehension is equivalent to the following nested loops:

```
result = {}
for element in json_lst:
    for k, v in element.items():
          result[int(k)] = v
```

Comment: This seemed to be the solution which worked with minimal changes to the original datafile. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Or try merging list of dictionaries:

```
>>> [i['1234'] for i in L1 if '1234' in i][0]
'hello world'
>>>
```

Whole thing:

```
>>> L1=[{
    "1234": "hello world"
}, 
{
    "5678": "roses are red"
}]
>>> [i['1234'] for i in L1 if '1234' in i][0]
'hello world'
>>>
```

Comment: @DanielMesejo Now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read this in as a python dictionary, where 1234 and 5678 are "keys" and the respective strings are the values. 
For example,

```
{
  1234: 'hello world', 
  5678: 'roses are red'
}
```

You can index into it as you have mentioned, `L1[1234]` and you will get 'hello world'.
You can read a bit about dictionaries [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: But how do you get that dict?

Answer (score 0):

Change your json like this

```
L1 = {
    "1234": "hello world",
    "5678": "roses are red"
}

# call it with quote or as string

print L1["1234"]
```

or create function

```
jsonList = [{
    "1234": "hello world"
}, 
{
    "5678": "roses are red"
}]


def L1(key):
  key = str(key)
  for i in jsonList:
    if key in i:
      return i[key]

print L1(5678)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are reading from a json file, when json is loaded the type of data is dictionary and you can directly read the keys of loaded data.
Still if you want to create a list out of it, please refer below code

My sample.json file

{
    "1234": {
        "id": "blabla",
        "iscategorical": "0"
    },
    "5678": {
        "id": "valore"
    },
    "8975": "value",
    "6985": {
        "id": "valore"
    }
}

Code in separate python file:

import json

import io

from collections import defaultdict

with io.open('sample.json') as data_file:

```
data_loaded = json.load(data_file)
```

print(data_loaded)

print(type(data_loaded))

l1 = defaultdict(list)

for key in data_loaded:

```
l1[key] = data_loaded[key]
```

print(l1)

print(l1['1234'])